# SQL Server connection on distributed Access front end

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm working on an application right now that requires a link to a couple of SQL Server tables. My windows network account has permission to connect to this server, but I am not going to be the only one using this application. I'm going to send it out for people to save to their PC or just put it on the company shared drive to use (I know, that's asking for problems sometimes). It's inconvenient to make a windows account for users to share because they would need to log out and in to use the app, so I was wondering if the application or ODBC connection file itself can store the credentials to access the table.

Should I configure the connection object to use something other than the windows login information (maybe a SQL server username/password), and just store the connection object in a shared location? I don't have much experience with this and haven't tried out many different solutions and I am open to suggestions.

Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: Create a Windows user group for your db users.  In SQL Server, grant the necessary permissions to that Windows group.  Add each of your users to that group.  And use Windows authentication for your connection to SQL Server.

Comment: @HansUp I like that - simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a comment to the question, one solution would be to

- create a User Group in Windows on the SQL Server,
- create a SQL Server login for that group,
- assign permissions within SQL Server to that login,
- and then just add or remove particular Windows Users from that group as required.

That way you don't need to mess with the various SQL Server permissions for each database user, and your application can connect to the SQL Server using Windows Authentication so you don't have to mess with saved SQL Server credentials (in connection strings, or elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can specify the username & password in the connection string -- ConnectionStrings.Com is highly recommended if you are having trouble with connection strings -- their first example for Sql Server is

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

The issue is security, if users can see this in a configuration file, they can do anything that account can do. You have to handle security within you application if you do this. Most apps that handle their own security have to create users and passwords in a database table (best not to store password at all, much less plaintext -- a one way hash is recommended).

One good strategy is the create a "login user" account with well known name and password, grant no read / write, etc. for that account at all, and grant execute access to single stored proc

```
IsLoginPermitted @ID, @PASS
```

When successful, IsLoginPermitted returns the ID & PASS for subsequent use (of course these are hidden from the user) and you create your new connection string based on these.